# Google API OAuth2.0 Working on localhost not on domain

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

I have a domain registered and hosted through amazon aws. I have the code hosted on an S3 bucket so I have chosen Google login and created authentication following the Google Login documentation:  [OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)

I believe it is related to the JavaScript origins in Google credentials. I have verified I am running the same scripting code that is succeeding on my local dev tomcat instance. However, I had this exact code working when I was on my .net domain and after switching to .com I can no longer connect with a "too many unauthenticated requests" timeout.

```
"errors": [
 {
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
"message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
"extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
 }
```

From google's api console

```
Authorized JavaScript origins
For use with requests from a browser. 
This is the origin URI of the client application. 
It can't contain a wildcard (http://*.example.com) or a path (http://example.com/subdir). 
If you're using a nonstandard port, you must include it in the origin URI.

http://localhost:8080
http://heaolumassage.com
```

Comment: "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded." Means that you are not authenticating your requests. check gapi.client.init make sure you have added your client id and client secret properly.

Comment: The original message seems to appear only a few times daily. 

I was not able to capture the exact text put it stated that for the project the project client id needed to add the domain to the whitelist. However, I have the domain set and the client ID matches.